# Using NatTable's ShowRowInViewportCommand

Tags: nattable

I was trying with NatTableExamples-1.4.0 and was trying to use `ShowRowInViewportCommand` with `_900_test\viewportSelection\ViewportSelectionHideShowDataLayerExample`.

I stored the `nattable` object obtained from `createExampleControl` method and `overloaded onStart()` method as follows:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
        nattable.doCommand(new ShowRowInViewportCommand(nattable.getLayer(), 35));    //didn't work
        nattable.doCommand(new SelectRowsCommand(nattable.getLayer(), 0, 35, false, false)); //worked, can see the row selected after scrolling down
    }
```

Here `SelectRowsCommand` worked. I saw that row 36 gets selected due to Index-position transformations, .

But I did not see the effect of `ShowRowInViewportCommand` in UI. I was expecting that the row 36 should be seen automatically .

`ShowRowInViewportCommandHandler` is in place. During debugging, I verified that the control reached to ShowRowInViewportCommandHandler.doCommand method.

What should I do to see automatic scrolling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a timing problem in your approach. You want to make something visible and scroll to that position that has not even been rendered yet. How should the scrolling be executed on something that is not rendered? The `Shell` is opened **AFTER** `onStart()`.

To execute auto-scrolling on startup you need to implement a listener that executes after rendering is done, e.g. by using a `PaintListener`.

```
this.nattable.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {

    @Override
    public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
        nattable.doCommand(new SelectRowsCommand(nattable, 0, 35, false, false));
        nattable.removePaintListener(this);
    }
});
```

BTW, you don't even need to execute the `ShowRowInViewportCommand` as the `SelectRowsCommand` automatically moves the selected row into the viewport.

Comment: I used the above code with many examples, it worked except for _513_FreezeExample. I understand that the layers are different. How to do SelectRowsCommand with _513_FreezeExample?